# Push Custom Report to Multiple Sites via API, Programming, or SQL

Tags: custom-reports

I oversee dozens of CiviCRM sites running on the same server (each with its own DB) and want to push out custom reports to all of them. I would like to be able to register the report and create a new report template.

Is there a way to automate this without having to use the UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap this custom report up into an extension -> then make that extension available in all your sites.

Comment: Great idea. I'm assuming that I can use civix to get started? https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/

Comment: Yes - absolutely; that's the easiest way to go